# MAX Value & its Corresponding Nodes in XSLT

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-1.0, xslt-2.0

I am a bit stuck in getting Max value of Qty from a simple structured XML. So need some help !

My XML is as below:

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TANK_DETAILS>
    <TABLES>
        <OUTPUT>
            <item>
                <AREA>INDIA</AREA>
                <MACHINE>T100</MACHINE>
                <MATERIAL>1111111</MATERIAL>
                <BATCH>100</BATCH>
                <QTY>18815.000</QTY>
            </item>
            <item>
                <AREA>INDIA</AREA>
                <MACHINE>T102</MACHINE>
                <MATERIAL>1111111</MATERIAL>
                <BATCH>200</BATCH>
                <QTY>100.000</QTY>
            </item>
            <item>
                <AREA>INDIA</AREA>
                <MACHINE>T103</MACHINE>
                <MATERIAL>1111111</MATERIAL>
                <BATCH>300</BATCH>
                <QTY>10000.000</QTY>
            </item>
            <item>
                <AREA>INDIA</AREA>
                <MACHINE>T101</MACHINE>
                <MATERIAL>1111111</MATERIAL>
                <BATCH>400</BATCH>
                <QTY>35550.000</QTY>
            </item>
            <item>
                <AREA>INDIA</AREA>
                <MACHINE>T104</MACHINE>
                <MATERIAL>1111111</MATERIAL>
                <BATCH>500</BATCH>
                <QTY>10100.000</QTY>
            </item>
            </OUTPUT>
            </TABLES>
        </TANK_DETAILS>
```

I want to get `<MACHINE>,<BATCH> & <Qty>` Where `<QTY>` is maximum.

Output XML should look like:

```
<Rowsets>
            <Rowset>
                <Row>
                    <MACHINE>T101</MACHINE>
                    <BATCH>400</BATCH>
                    <QTY>35550.000</QTY>
                </Row>
            </Rowset>
        </Rowsets>
```

The XSLT I'm Trying is as below:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
    <xsl:output indent="yes" method="xml" omit-xml-declaration="yes"/>
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

    <!-- Putting the maximum QTY from the list into a variable -->
    <xsl:variable name="max-QTY">
      <xsl:call-template name="find-max">

        <!-- Select the list of QTY elements -->
        <xsl:with-param name="QTY" select="//*[contains(local-name(), 'QTY')]"/>
      </xsl:call-template>
    </xsl:variable>


    <xsl:template match="*">
        <!-- Displaying the result -->
        <QTY>
            <xsl:value-of select="$max-QTY"/>
        </QTY>
    </xsl:template>


    <!-- This template works recursively on the list of QTY. -->
    <xsl:template name="find-max">
        <xsl:param name="QTY"/>
        <!-- The value of the first QTY in this list. -->
        <xsl:variable name="this-QTY">
      <xsl:value-of select="$QTY[position() = 1]"/>
    </xsl:variable>

        <xsl:choose>
            <xsl:when test="$QTY">
                <!-- The maximum value of the remaining QTY in this list. -->
                <xsl:variable name="other-QTY">
          <xsl:call-template name="find-max">
            <xsl:with-param name="QTY" select="$QTY[position() != 1]"/>
          </xsl:call-template>
        </xsl:variable>
                <!-- Return the maximum of this QTYand the remaining QTY. -->
                <xsl:choose>
                    <xsl:when test="$other-QTY&gt; $this-QTY">
                        <xsl:value-of select="$other-QTY"/>
                    </xsl:when>
                    <xsl:otherwise>
                        <xsl:value-of select="$this-QTY"/>
                    </xsl:otherwise>
                </xsl:choose>
            </xsl:when>
            <!-- We've reached the last QTY in the list. -->
            <xsl:otherwise/>
        </xsl:choose>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Output I'm getting is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<QTY>35550.000</QTY>
```

So I am able to find Maximum `<QTY>` but I am struggling to get the respective `<MACHINE> & <BATCH>` for max `<QTY>`.

I'm sure I am making a minor mistake but I'm very much stuck and facing a coders' block.

Also, if there is a better way to find max , please provide the optimal answer. That would be helpful.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would simply sort the `item`s by `QTY` and then output the first (in descending sort order) or last (in ascending sort order):

```
<xsl:stylesheet
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    version="1.0">

  <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>
  <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

  <xsl:template match="TABLES">
      <Rowsets>
          <Rowset>
              <xsl:for-each select="OUTPUT/item">
                  <xsl:sort select="QTY" data-type="number" order="descending"/>
                  <xsl:if test="position() = 1">
                      <Row>
                          <xsl:copy-of select="MACHINE | BATCH | QTY"/>
                      </Row>
                  </xsl:if>
              </xsl:for-each>
          </Rowset>
      </Rowsets>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/94hvTz2 has an online sample.

Comment: This works like a charm. I did not know it is this easy to implement. You just need to know syntaxes :) Thanks a ton !!!

Answer (score 1):

I would start this off by having a key, like:

```
<xsl:key name="kQTY" match="QTY" use="."/>
```

Then, I would store the maximum QTY in a variable, such as:

```
<xsl:variable name="maxQTY">
    <xsl:for-each select="//item">
        <xsl:sort select="key('kQTY', QTY)" order="descending"/>
        <xsl:if test="position()=1">
            <xsl:value-of select="QTY"/>
        </xsl:if>
    </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:variable>
```

Then, in the template that matches the `OUTPUT` node, I would filter the item that contains the maximum QTY, such as:

```
<xsl:template match="OUTPUT">
    <Rowset>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="item[QTY=$maxQTY]"/>
    </Rowset>
</xsl:template>
```

Then a template needed to filter the item contents:

```
<xsl:template match="item">
    <xsl:apply-templates select="MACHINE,BATCH,QTY"/>
</xsl:template>
```

A few matching templates for cleanup

```
<xsl:template match="TANK_DETAILS">
    <xsl:apply-templates/>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="TABLES">
    <Rowsets>
        <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </Rowsets>
</xsl:template>
```

and an identity template:

```
<xsl:template match="node()|@*">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
```

The whole stylesheet is as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    exclude-result-prefixes="xs"
    version="2.0">

    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>
    <xsl:output indent="yes" omit-xml-declaration="yes"/>

    <xsl:key name="kQTY" match="QTY" use="."/>

    <xsl:variable name="maxQTY">
        <xsl:for-each select="//item">
            <xsl:sort select="key('kQTY', QTY)" order="descending"/>
            <xsl:if test="position()=1">
                <xsl:value-of select="QTY"/>
            </xsl:if>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:variable>

    <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="OUTPUT">
        <Rowset>
                <xsl:apply-templates select="item[QTY=$maxQTY]"/>
        </Rowset>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="item">
        <xsl:apply-templates select="MACHINE,BATCH,QTY"/>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="TANK_DETAILS">
        <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="TABLES">
        <Rowsets>
            <xsl:apply-templates/>
        </Rowsets>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

See it in action [here](http://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/bdxtpV).

Comment: I like how you have explained in detail. But if you see @Martin Honnen answer, it is crisp & clear and seems more optimal. Please do check his answer !

Comment: As I do not know the whole scope of your style sheet, I just followed your lead in getting the max Qty. I just presume that you will use it somewhere else. Martin's answer is straightforward, yes.

Comment: I completely agree. Your answer is useful too in case I need to use max qty later somewhere in my XSLT. Really appreciate your efforts.